# Adding picklist values on microsite page in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, microsites

I have designed microsite page and on this page i have Email, city, city area and shop name

Client has provided sample data for three fields but their requirement is if i selected any value from city then only areas under that city should be populated in picklist area like dependent picklist.

Firstly i need to add this sample data into marketing cloud and then retreive using AMP script. Where should i add this sample data?? I am very new to SFMC

Any help would be really appreciable !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Data Extensions in SFMC to store the City and corresponding sample data. Then you can use [AMPScript's lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) function.

There is a [very nice article](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/) from Adam Spriggs as well

Comment: Thanks for your help Maneesh.. But Email is also in the form and initially i just want to add sample data for only city, city area, shop.  Is it possible that first i create one data extension which has only city, city area, shop and add sample data into this and after that create a new data extension which will have all attribute present in form.  can I use two different data extension. I am confused.. Kindly suggest

Comment: Yes you can create as many data extensions as you like. Use the first one for testing and then later use the second one for real data.